# Jhipster microservices : How to create dynamic instances on microservices in production?

Tags: java, jhipster, microservices, production-environment

I am using JHipster with 3 microservices (microservice1, microservice2, microservice3) applications, 1 JHipster registry application, and the API gateway. All applications are working as needed. I can  run my 5 applications in production without problem in mode one instance by application :

- microservice1 => One instance
- **microservice2 => One instance**
- microservice3 => One instance
- jhipster registry=> One instance
- API Gateway=> One instance

I want to have the following instance dynamically or with some automation :

- microservice1 => One instance
- **microservice2 => One, two or more instances**
- microservice3 => One instance
- jhipster registry=> One instance
- API Gateway=> One instance

But I wonder how to instance dynamically or manually more instance of microservice2. If I want to create a new instance of service what is the best practices? :
 - In Jhipster configuration are set in application-prod.yml. The port is set are the creation of the application. I just avec one server.  So if I cannot create a new instance on the same server!  There is be a conflict IP/port because the port is configured in the application-prod.yml. How to solve it? I think it's not a good idea to create multiple configuration files with different ports in case I have to run others instances of my microservices.

- Is there another way to solve my problem?

Thank you for reading and for your ideas.

Comment: How are you deploying your production instances?  For example, with Docker only your gateway's IP address needs to be exposed publicly, allowing you to run several microservices using the same port privately

Comment: If you don't use Docker you can still force a different port using command line, see spring boot doc.

Comment: @JonRuddell   thanks for your answer.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks also

Comment: You mean i have to pass the port while starting  a new instance ? This implies i must reserve some ports for each microservices. Before starting new ones, must check which ports are used and start with an unused port. I see. But i am looking a way to automate the process or starting a new instance without thinking about port to choose. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the following configuration : `server.port=0`

Your Spring Boot application will scan for a free port on your OS and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try some containerization ([docker](https://www.docker.com/) or [rkt](https://github.com/rkt/rkt/)) to deploy microservice.
This will give you flexibility of deployment, because in containerization each and every container have their own IP, so port and IP does not conflict.

Definitely after this you required some service discovery to discover your microservices to call from other microservice.

Answer (score 0):

What we have done in our project for same thing is, we deployed same instance by creating new profile for the dynamic microservice.

Just make sure that you connect to your registry and gatway properly with new profile, jhipster will take care everthing.

```
MICROSERVICE A 1   (dynamic) SERVER1
MICROSERVICE A 2   (dynamic) SERVER2
MICROSERVICE B  (deployedin) SERVER1
GATEWAY  (deployedin) SERVER1
REGISTRY  (deployedin) SERVER1
```